# Timezone is not updating with WiFi and ethernet network in Android

Tags: wi-fi, settings, internet, time-zones

I am working with Android **AOSP**. When I connect my Android device with **cellular network**, then the timezone is updating (if I enable the "auto-update time zone" option). But if I connect my device with **WiFi** or **ethernet network**, then the timezone is not updating (even if the "auto-update time zone" option is enabled).

I studied some forums, they are saying that the timezone will not update with WiFi and ethernet network.

Is it right? Please give some summary regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Time synchronization via Wifi/Ethernet bases on the [NTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). All NTP server are running with UTC time, hence they can not provide a time zone.

If if they would the time-zone would be useless, as an NTP server can be located anywhere in the world. Typically one NTP DNS name consists on multiple NTP servers, and based on a region the closest server is selected, but that still does not mean that the server is located in the same time-zone as you are.

Only the cellular network has the [Network Identity and Time Zone (NITZ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NITZ) service which provides not only time but also the current time-zone. As a mobile network cell is limited to a very small area it is possible to deliver correct time zone data via cellular.